# How to install and use Apache Spark with restricted access?

Tags: java, apache-spark, windows-7

I'm doing an internship this summer at a very big company and I'm going to be working on a machine learning project. My manager told me to use Apache Spark for my project. This is all very new to me. I'm learning machine learning and how to use Apache Spark.

Since I'm working for a big company, security is tight here. I do NOT have admin privileges, so I need to know exactly what admin-stuff I need to do to set up my PC with Apache Spark so I can contact a technician and tell him exactly what to do.

So far I only have installed Eclipse with Java JDK 8. I also downloaded the Apache Spark 2.1.1 prebuild with Hadoop from their website. I can't seem to find any installation guide on their website. I also don't know what else do I need to download. I also have to ask for install permissions since I can't install on my own.

Any help or links to other sources/references is greatly appreciated.

My operating system is Windows 7 and I do NOT have admin privileges.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://freecontent.manning.com/wp-content/uploads/how-to-start-developing-spark-applications-in-eclipse.pdf

Try the above link for Eclipse. Also, you don't install Spark as you do other programs in Windows. Just go to the bin folder of Spark and open a command prompt. Run spark-shell.cmd

Comment: I did try that, but nothing happened. When I try to run it, I get the following error: " 'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command or batch file " I think this is because one admin made a mistake when setting the environment variables... Right now my path is set to:
Path = C:\Program Files\Java
I don't know why he did that.

Comment: There are just too many variables to give exact answer here. But spaces in path do cause some issues. Keep that path in like "C:\Program Files\Java"